# Tabview as sticky header in react-native

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm using one third party library for tabview in react native.ie, [React-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view). I need to create this tabview as a sticky header in table view. Below is exactly how I need that. When I scroll the page the banner will go up but those 3 tabs remain on top. Can someone help on this, please?

[image]

Comment: No. Still trying to achieve it

Comment: the only difference is am using [tab](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab)

Comment: Are you using react-navigation? If so you can use a StackNavigator and and as a child your TabNavigator. Then you can subscribe to the onScroll event of your scrollView, and animate the height of the header of the StackNavigator as you scroll down.

Comment: @JanPeter i tried but might didn't get you right can you provide example or link code

Comment: Well, I could try to write it myself as an example. Don't know if there is any tutorial on this. But you'll have to wait a little^^

Comment: @AbdulHameed do you need a StackNavigator or is it sufficient to use the TabNavigator?

Comment: @JanPeter I need StackNavigator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a sample project on [Github](https://github.com/JanPeter/RN-NavigationHeaderAnimation). It should do the trick. I used native animations, so I can only animate transform and opacity, which should be pretty fast. One of the problems though is that the nested navigators are not connected, but you should be able to do that. Can't be that hard :P

And for now the banner is shown even if you switch the tab, which may not be the behaviour you want. But I think overall this repo gives you a good starting point. At least I hope so :)

If you want to know how to nest navigators with views in between them you can have a look at a second repo on [Github](https://github.com/JanPeter/RN-TabStackNavigatorFAB) I made today for another SO question. Maybe I'll write a Medium post about this topic. Depends on my spare time I guess :P

Comment: Wow, that's cool @Jan Peter. I appreciate your efforts. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer above with a second repository where you can look up how to connect the nested navigator properly :)

Comment: @JanPeter, your solution helped me a lot. Can you please tell me how to control scroll acceleration. The header section and down section are not accelerating simultaneously. How can I achieve that?